# MySQL fails once per day. How to change "localhost" to 127.0.0.1

Tags: sql, networking

I get a can't connect through this socket once per day.

Is this datadir correct?:

[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

```
Aborted connection 1270592 to db: 'leechprotect' user: 'leechprotect' host: 'localhost' (Got timeout reading communication packets)


PHP Warning:  mysql_connect() [<a href='function.mysql-connect'>function.mysql-connect</a>]: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (11) in wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1037
```

QUESTION: How to change the sql connect from "localhost" to 127.0.0.1 as recommended by many people online. Do I have to do that via bind-address?

Comment: Does the 'outage' happen at the same time each day?  Perhaps when a backup is run, logs are rotated or some other scheduled task is being executed?  If so, then disable that task.

Comment: What's the justification behind trying to change to 127.0.0.1?  I can't imagine a situation where that would help you connect to the socket.

Comment: Thanks Shane, that's true. The only problem is that right now I'm pretty clueless why I get that error that Mysql cant connect to the socket.

Answer (score 0):

Find your PHP db config file and change `$host` from `'localhost'` to `'localhost:/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'`.

Comment: Quanta, what exactly does it? I already specified the path to the mysql.sock im my.cnf .. isn't that enough?

Comment: No, that's not enough. my.cnf is used by `mysqld`, PHP DB config by PHP scripts.

Answer (score 0):

1) If the error always happens at the same time, see which cron jobs run at that time. Cron configuration files (crotabs) are `/etc/crontab` and `/var/spool/cron/*`; see `man crontab` for their format description.

2) Check MySQL error log (in Linux, it's typically `/var/lib/mysql/*.err` ) for anything that happens around the moment the error occurs.